# How to create modules in Design Section and Edit Header in each module at Divi Custom Module?

Tags: javascript, php, css, reactjs

Currently I am working with Custom Divi Module and editing my own customized modules for a project.
Do you have any idea regarding the customization in the Design Section at Divi Builder on how to create custom modules at the Design Section?

[image: here is the image of the design section]

Here is my simple code for each modules. Unfortunately, each of these are directing to the content section:

```
    'account' => array(
        'label'           => esc_html__('Instagram User ID','custmod-test'),
        'type'            => 'text',
        'option_category' => 'basic_option',
        'description'     => esc_html__('An account User ID. Separate multiple IDs by commas.','custmod-test'),
        'toggle_slug'     => 'main_content',
    ),
```

[image: how to edit this header in the custom module? anyone?]

Please don't hesitate to ask if you want me to clarify something.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please attempt to answer the question on your own and show the results of your attempts. Do not just come to SO and expect people to solve your problems for you.

Comment: by the way, already answered.
answer: added tab_slug